# TextureArray with image2D/Computeshader

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, compute-shader, glteximage2d

I am currently trying to bind multiple Textures to a Computeshader. Because there is only a small limited amount of image unites available, I thought of binding a `TextureArray` with the advantage of doing less bindings with more Textures. As far as I know `TextureArrays` can only be typed by Sampler with `sampler2DArrays`. I however am useing images so i can use `imageLoad()/imageStore()`. Is there a workaround to use `TextureArrays` with `image2D` or am I forced to use other methodes like `Texture Atlases`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specialised image type for 2d array textures: `gimage2DArray`. `imageLoad` and `imageStore` have overloads that allow to access array images with a 3-dimensional index where the third dimension specifies the array level.

[Source](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store)